# What does the dbo.aspnet_schemaversions table exactly do?

Tags: .net, sql-server

I tried googling for an answer but I didn't find any direct reference. I know it's part of the membership provider. However, I don't find any relationships with other tables. No foreign key or dependencies or anything. Only a couple of stored procedures depend on the table, and are those that insert, update and delete from the table.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You missed `dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion` which selects from it. presumably the providers raise an error if this doesn't return the expected result.

Comment: Oh okay thanks =). I missed the sp that selects from it. Anyway I deleted all the rows of aspnet_schemaversion and everything is running okay, so I'm completely lost =(. (I'm running a DNN environment which uses the aspnet tables)

Comment: Googling that stored procedure finds [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/thread/ac0770af-a781-4558-9f2f-f8bea17665be) so clearly there are some modules that at least call the procedure.

Comment: Great! That's very nice! It probably does not apply to my DNN environment but you found a nice application at last! Thanks!